# "were also been accused" grammatically correct?

Tags: past-tense

> Others accused Mr Glavin of inappropriate touching, and leading with intimidation and fear. Mr Leman and Mr Norman **were also been accused** of sexual harassment by former staff.

https://www.bbc.com/news/world-us-canada-53815705

"were also been" a typo or a correct grammar?

Answer (score 2):

It's a typo. The writer has accidentally jumbled up the following forms:

> - Mr Leman and Mr Norman were also accused...
> - Mr Leman and Mr Norman have also been accused...